# tcp connection problem on n73 and nokia 5800

Tags: symbian

Please help me with solving the following issue.
I am trying to connect to a static IP with TCP connection (RSocket). I have N73 device, which uses Vodaphone live(service Provider). As the application tries to connect to the specified IP and Port through the specified service provider, the screen shows connecting for a long time, but no error or connection occurs.

If I try through Nokia 5800 with WLan(Wifi), I am able to connect to the desired IP port and work. But here too the connection through Vodaphone Live(service Provider) to static IP server does not work.

FYI: The GPRS is activated for both devices.

Please provide me any solution, or service provider settings that I may be missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your Mobile Network Operator could very well be filtering all non-HTTP traffic.

I suggest running a http server on the statically-IPed device and using the Symbian HTTP API.